# I'm trying to pass a error if email exists then send a error saying it exists in AJAX but the code isn't working?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

This is the code i have for the ajax, every thing works but it wont send the errors that the email exists. it gives the error on the createuser.php page when I view it in the console log.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#signup_button").click(function(){
    if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")){
        alert("you must agree to terms");
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "system/api/createuser.php",
        type: "post",

        data: {email: $("#signup_email").val(), name: $("#signup_name").val(), password: $("#signup_password").val()}
    }).done(function(response){
        var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
        if (resp.errors != ""){
            alert(resp.errors);
        }else{

        }

       });
    });
});
```

This is the php code for the createuser.php.

```
<?php
include ("../include.php");
$return = array();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$user = User::createuser($email, $password, $name, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,0);

if ($user == false){
    $return['errors'] = "A user with that email exits!!";
}else{
    $return = "";
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    echo "This is a test: " . $user->email . "   " . $user->name . "\n";
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Here is the createuser function.

```
    global  $db, $user_id;
    // check that email is active //

    $check = $db->query("SELECT * From users where email = '".$email."'");
    $check21 = $db->fetch($check);

    if(isset($check21['email'])){
        return false;
        $db->error("user exits");
    }else{
        $check2 = $db->fetch($check);
        $options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
    ];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);



    $user_created = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (email, password, name, strength, creativity, stealth, integrity, investigation, charm, fundraising, intimidation, manipulation, job_id, party_id, admin) VALUES  ('$email','$hashed_password', '$name', 
                '$strength','$creativity', '$stealth', '$integrity',
                '$investigation', '$charm', '$fundraising', '$intimidation',
                '$manipulation', '$job', '$party', '$admin' )");


            if($user_created == true){

                $users = $db->fetch($db->query("SELECT user_id From users where email='".$email."' ") );
                $user_id = $users['user_id'];

                return new User($user_id);
            }elseif($user_created == false)
                return false;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You question only has half your code what does the php look like? And what error do you see in the console?

Comment: Also, are you seeing the response in your browser's dev tools? Can you share that?

Comment: Are you sure that `User::createuser()` returns false when the user exists?

Comment: In the console log this it the message i'm getting. I'm getting my error but its not alerting me on the page. The alert("that user exists already!!");

Comment: {errors: "A user with that email exits!!"}
errors
:
"A user with that email exits!!"

Comment: yes it returns false

Comment: I added the createuser.php and the createuser(); so you can see my code.

Comment: I dont understand how you see the json in the js console, as you dont log it. Is it part of a javascript error? Please give more details

Comment: Here is the link to a image so you can see my error. [ https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SOeDB9Jb84Ip8QoQQ4k9xPn3N6IpleNHaCaiXkOX-xs/edit?usp=sharing ]

Comment: In the javascript I posted not giving my alert("resp.errors");

Comment: What about the console tab in the browser tools? Anything there?

Comment: yes if you go the the link i shared on google docs. You can see my error messages show on the createuser.php but not on my main page with the js that alerts me that I have a error but it don't send a error.

Comment: I'm only seeing a shot of the `network` tab in your Google doc. I mean the `console` tab next to it on the toolbar.  Just a hunch, change `var resp = $.parseJSON...` to just `var resp = response;`. Obviously you won't leave it like this, it's just a test.

Comment: We need to know why `createuser` is returning `false`. There are three lines where it might return `false`. Which one is it?

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console log.
`www.testgames.org/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (create_user.js:19)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:5)`

Comment: In that case I assume you've changed something, and `createuser` no longer returns false. This means it's doing `echo "This is a test: " . $user->email . "   " . $user->name . "\n";` before it `echo`es the JSON string. So you get something like `This is a test: user@example.com   me\n""`. So `$.parseJSON` tries to parse this, but of course it's not valid JSON. It doesn't need to go any further than the first character to know it's invalid, hence "Unexpected token T". In short, it now fails because of that log line you added in `createuser.php`.

Comment: I'd hope there's some way of logging to a file instead of the client. But I couldn't tell you how. It's been a while since I've done PHP.